# Prevent scrolling when mouse enters WPF ComboBox dropdown

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, .net-4.5

When a `ComboBox` has a large number of items, its dropdown will become scrollable. When the user invokes this dropdown, and moves the mouse cursor to enter the bounds of the dropdown from the bottom, the dropdown immediately scrolls one or more items down the list (*from goobering: also happens when exiting the bounds via the bottom edge*).

This scrolling is not intuitive, as the list does not scroll upwards when entering the bounds from the top.

How can we disable the automatic scrolling behavior?

In Visual Studio this behavior can be observed via the member dropdown on the code editor's navigation bar (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

Comment: To clarify the behavior, this seems to fire whenever the cursor moves over the lowest boundary of the ComboBox dropdown *in either direction*, top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you running?

Comment: I've submitted [feedback on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1255745/combobox-popup-scrolls-unexpectedly-when-mouse-enters-its-bounds-from-bottom) in case this is a bug.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use a Behaviour (or rather behaviour-like Attached Property) to subscribe to the `RequestBringIntoView` event of the `ComboBoxItems` and then set the `RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs.Handled` to true. 
This can also be done on a small scale using an `EventSetter` and codebehind.

```
 <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">                    
     <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="OnRequestBringIntoView"/>
 </Style>

private void OnRequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    //Allows the keyboard to bring the items into view as expected:
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up))
        return;            

    e.Handled = true;            
}
```

**Edit**

I found that you can get the same effect by handling the RequestBringIntoView event on the `ItemsPanel` rather than the items themselves. But same result:

```
<ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel RequestBringIntoView="OnRequestBringIntoView"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Not on the `ComboBox` itself - as was written it has to be at the `ComboBoxItem`. You can put together a quick demo showing it works by explicitly adding `ComboBoxItems` to a comboBox and wiring up to their event. It works.

Comment: I see. This code does avoid the scrolling for mouse events. More logic would be required to allow scrolling for keyboard events as the user would expect, but this code does answer my original question.

Comment: @JoeGaggler I found that it also works from the` ItemsPanel` event as well - which reduces the number of eventHandlers that are hooked-up.

Comment: @JoeGaggler I added a simple example check to see if the keyboard up/down keys are pressed. Interestingly the page-up/down works without a check.

Comment: The first example affects the style of the ComboBoxItems, the second one does not so I'd rather use the second one.

Comment: Both examples make the search to not work in the ComboBox when typing a text, because they basically prevent the key down event on the control. Me having a list with many elements the search is vital. So be careful if you use these solutions, they come with many side effects.

Comment: The best solution I've found is to add `if (((UIElement)e.Source).IsKeyboardFocusWithin) e.Handled = true;` to the `ComboBox_RequestBringIntoView` method. This prevents the undesired auto scroll but lets the filtering by typing on the keyboard work as well.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell this seems to be caused by the items at the bottom of the light being "partially displayed", where an item is truncated by the container.  When the mouse goes over a partial item like this WPF scrolls the entire item in to view, which can sometimes leave another partial item at the bottom.

In Winforms this can be fixed by setting the `.IntegralHeight`, but no such property exists in WPF from what I can tell.  If all the items in your combobox have the same height you could bind the height of the list of the combobox to a multiple of the item height, for example, display 10 x 20px tall items, set it to 200.

Comment: This is a great theory, but it did not appear to work when I tried it out. I was able to explicitly set the item height using the `ItemTemplate` property, then set the `MaxDropDownHeight` to be an integral of the item height. The behavior still occurred when moving the mouse onto the border of the drop dropdown. I also tried adjusting the height +/- 1px to make sure there was not an off-by-one issue.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer from Andrew Hanlon prevents the list from scrolling to the selected item when opened.

I had to add this into the event handler ("list" is the ComboBox):

```
private void OnRequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    //Allows the keyboard to bring the items into view as expected:
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up))
        return;

    // Allows to bring the selected item into view:
    if (((ComboBoxItem)e.TargetObject).Content == list.SelectedItem)
        return;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd same issue in my application so I've styled the Combobox's `PART_Popup` to solve the issue in this way:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
       IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
       AllowsTransparency="True" 
       Focusable="False"
       PopupAnimation="Slide">

    <Grid MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">

        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder"
                Background="White"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                Margin="0 2 0 0"/>

        <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" 
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

If you add `Margin` in `ScrollViewer` (eg.`<ScrollViewer Margin="1" ...`) it'd start scrolling down automatically.

Comment: This does nothing for me.