# WPF - ComboBox - Prevent Scrolling - WIthout using Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

## Issue

I need to prevent scrolling through the `ComboBox` selected items when the mouse hovers over the closed `ComboBox`.

I have seen this done using code behind (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638148/prevent-scrolling-when-mouse-enters-wpf-combobox-dropdown)), but I need to do it without code behind, in a way that could be easily reused throughout the project.

For example, elsewhere in our project we use [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to do make a `StaticResource` that can easily be added where required.

## Question

Is there a way to make a `StaticResource` for the `ComboBox` that could prevent scrolling?

Is there an interface like `IValueConveter` that could be used in place of the `EventSetter` `Handler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I need to do it without code behind, in a way that could be easily reused throughout the project.

So wrap the code-behind functionality in an attached behaviour:

```
public static class NoScrollingBehaviour
{
    public static bool GetEnabled(ComboBox comboBox) =>
        (bool)comboBox.GetValue(EnabledProperty);

    public static void SetEnabled(ComboBox comboBox, bool value) =>
        comboBox.SetValue(EnabledProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Enabled",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(NoScrollingBehaviour),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnEnabledChanged));

    private static void OnEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)d;
        if (GetEnabled(comboBox))
        {
            FrameworkElementFactory stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
            stackPanel.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.RequestBringIntoViewEvent, new RequestBringIntoViewEventHandler(OnRequestBringIntoView));
            comboBox.ItemsPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate() { VisualTree = stackPanel };
        }
    }

    private static void OnRequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up))
            return;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

You can then easily reuse it for different `ComboBox` elements:

```
<ComboBox local:NoScrollingBehaviour.Enabled="true" />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It doesn't get to the `e.Handled = true;`. I made changes to AddHandler directly to comboBox, and now it gets to `e.Handled = true;` but still scrolls regardless

Comment: What is not working? You asked on how "do it without code behind" and the answer to that question is to use an attached behaviour. You can implement the event handler exactly as you would do in the code-behind of a view.

Comment: You are right, this does answer the question of a how to do it without code behind, and I will mark it as solved for that.

However, for some reason marking the `Handled` property as `true` on `RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs`  does not work. Should I open a separate question for that?

Comment: Yes, please do. And make sure that you include all relevant details to be able to reproduce the issue from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have posted the new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111993/c-sharp-wpf-combobox-prevent-scrolling-when-hovering-over-selected-combobo)