# C# - WPF - ComboBox - Prevent scrolling when hovering over a focused ComboBox (using an attached property)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

## Background

I need to prevent a `ComboBox` from scrolling when hovering over it (while it is focused) and scrolling using the mouse wheel.

In this circumstance I cannot use code behind, so I am using an attached property.

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76101509/wpf-combobox-prevent-scrolling-without-using-code-behind/76102039?noredirect=1#comment134228989_76102039) to adapt the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638148/prevent-scrolling-when-mouse-enters-wpf-combobox-dropdown) from code behind to attached property.

## Code

Here is my `xaml`:

```xml
<ComboBox comboBox:NoScrollingBehaviour.Enabled="True"
          IsEditable="True" 
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
          IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" 
          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
          Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MySourceProperty, ElementName=MyElementName}"/>
```

Here is my code that `comboBox:NoScrollingBehaviour` links to:

```cs
public static class NoScrollingBehaviour
{
    public static bool GetEnabled(ComboBox comboBox) =>
        (bool)comboBox.GetValue(EnabledProperty);

    public static void SetEnabled(ComboBox comboBox, bool value) =>
        comboBox.SetValue(EnabledProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Enabled",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(NoScrollingBehaviour),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnEnabledChanged));

    private static void OnEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)d;
        if (GetEnabled(comboBox))
        {
            FrameworkElementFactory stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
            stackPanel.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.RequestBringIntoViewEvent, new RequestBringIntoViewEventHandler(OnRequestBringIntoView));
            comboBox.ItemsPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate() { VisualTree = stackPanel };
        }
    }

    private static void OnRequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up))
            return;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

## What I have Tried

It only reaches `OnRequestBringIntoView` when *clicking* on the `ComboBox`, but not when scrolling with the mouse wheel.

I also tried adding in an event for `MouseWheelEvent` for `stackPanel`, but that never seems to get triggered.

I then tried adding in an event for `MouseWheelEvent` for `comboBox`, but it only gets triggered when scrolling using the mouse wheel when the `ComboBox` is *not* focused.

## Question

How do I prevent the `ComboBox` from scrolling (with the mouse wheel) when it is focused?

Comment: How does it scroll when it is selected? What item does it scroll to?

Comment: Sorry, I meant focused, I will edit the question

Comment: My `ItemsSource` is a `List<string>`

Comment: When it is focused, and I hover over it, and scroll with the mouse wheel, it scrolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to disable scrolling using the mouse wheel, you could handle the `PreviewMouseWheel` event for the `ComboBox` itself in the attached behaviour:

```
public static class NoScrollingBehaviour
{
    public static bool GetEnabled(ComboBox comboBox) =>
        (bool)comboBox.GetValue(EnabledProperty);

    public static void SetEnabled(ComboBox comboBox, bool value) =>
        comboBox.SetValue(EnabledProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Enabled",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(NoScrollingBehaviour),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnEnabledChanged));

    private static void OnEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)d;
        if (GetEnabled(comboBox))
            comboBox.PreviewMouseWheel += OnPreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    private static void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves that problem. The next one is how do I still allow the parent to scroll? (I will post another question when I am allowed to do so)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76112864/c-sharp-wpf-prevent-scrolling-this-element-but-allow-scrolling-parent) is my next question